# Iterating through enum with EnumMember attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

Given the following `enum`:

```
public enum JobTypes
{
    [EnumMember (Value = "IN PROGRESS")]
    IN_PROGRESS,
    SUBMITTED,
    [EnumMember (Value = "IN REVIEW")]
    IN_REVIEW
}
```

I am iterating through these as follows:

```
foreach (var jobType in Enum.GetValues (typeof(JobTypes))) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0,3:D} 0x{0:X} {1}", Enum.Parse(typeof(JobTypes), jobType.ToString()), jobType);
}
```

**Output:**

```
// The example displays the following output: 
// 0     0x00000000     IN_PROGRESS 
// 1     0x00000001     SUBMITTED
// 2     0x00000002     IN_REVIEW
```

**Expected:**

```
// The example displays the following output: 
// 0     0x00000000     IN PROGRESS // no _ character 
// 1     0x00000001     SUBMITTED
// 2     0x00000002     IN REVIEW // no _ character
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you calling `Enum.Parse` when you've already *got* `jobType` as a value of type `JobTypes`...

Comment: @JonSkeet It's actually from the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But that's when it's iterating over the *names* (at which point it's reasonable to parse the name you've got) - you're iterating over the *values*. Why would you take a value, call `ToString()` on it, and then parse the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet My code actually uses `GetNames` rather than `GetValues` so I guess I did too many CTRL-Z's before I pasted the question?

Comment: I faced a similar issue, to iterate over an enum where few members had descriptions but not all. I wrote an extension to get description (of course using reflection) of the member, if description was empty (null) the extension returned the Name of member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EnumMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute) only affects serialization:

> The EnumMemberAttribute enables fine control of the names of the enumerations as they are serialized.

It doesn't have any effect on the result of calling `ToString()` on the value, which is effectively what you're doing here.

Comment: I see, thanks for that. Is there a way to convert enum's to include spaces?

Comment: @gotnull: Well you could fetch the attributes yourself with reflection - or just replace `_` with ` ` everywhere using `string.Replace`...

Comment: Yeah, I think that'll have to do for now. Thanks.